# ng-repeat sum values in textbox dynamically in angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

hi all I am using `angular js` i am trying to do sum the values were placed in  a ng-repeat text box based row I tried it's sum the whole data anyone can help how to solve the issue

here I attached my fiddle[:https://jsfiddle.net/rjj/zm9941tm/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/rjj/zm9941tm/1/)

Comment: `<input type="text" ng-value="x.value1*1 + x.value2*1">`

Answer (score 2):

`<td><input type="text" ng-model="x.result = +x.value1 + +x.value2;"></td>`

This would fix the issue. Set the result as a sum of value1 and value2 and +has been added to change string to numbers for easy sum. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zm9941tm/4/

Comment: thanks @gauravmuk but i need use function like stzoannos help

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
ng-model="x.result = x.value1 + x.value2"
```

Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kL315y2h/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array that you are using in ng-repeat is "myArray", you could add a function in the controller like:

```
$scope.calculateSum = function calculateSum(array) {

  var sum = 0;
  array.forEach(function (value) {
    this.sum += value;
  }, this); 

  return sum;
}
```

and after the ng-repeat table, you add another element with value `{{calculateSum(myArray}}`

Comment: make me fiddle @stzoannos i am also doing like your concept i need

Comment: any suggestion how to trigger the function

Comment: well, in this case we need to assume that instead of an array of objects you have an array of arrays in the records variable. Is that fine for you?

Comment: like: [
    {
      values: [0,0]
    },
    {
       values: [0,0]
    },
    {
      values: [0,0]
    },
    {
      values: [0,0]
    }
  ]

Answer (score 0):

Tried some thing with static values ...hope this may helps you

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('EditorController', function($scope) {
$scope.records = [
    {
      "value1" : 10,
      "value2" : 20,
   "result" :0
    },
    {
       "value1" : 30,
      "value2" : 40,
   "result" :0
    },
    {
      "value1" : 50,
      "value2" : 60,
   "result" :0
    },
    {
      "value1" : 70,
      "value2" : 80,
   "result" :0
    }
  ]
  $scope.func=function(x){
    return x.value1+x.value2;
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
 
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="EditorController">
      <table  border="1">

<tr>
 <th>A</th>
 <th>B</th>
 <th>Result</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.value1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.value2"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  ng-init="result = func(x);" ng-model="result"></td>
    
</tr>
</table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i didnt understand